# How to set radioButton's default selected in TKinter to be the one that was selected before the program ended?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have two radio buttons in my GUI application, I am able to select which radio button is set to default by using the .set() method. But how can I leave the default one be the one that the user last choose in his/her last session before closing the program?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do it like you handle any other data - save it in a file or database, and then read it from a file or database. Have you tried that?

Comment: IDLE uses `configparser` and .cfg files to save and restore user options, but this might be overkill for you.   Depending on what you want to save, and whether you want the file to be readable and editable by people, you can instead use use marshal, pickle, json, or a file format that you design specifically for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use persistent data.

Say that the radiobutton's value that the user set in 1, save 1 to a file, and focus the radiobutton to the variable pulled from the file at next restart.
This might help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would try it.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it. Thanks again.